# COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

[image][image]
[image]

I am new to docker. I created a solution with a WebAPI project, I used the command
`docker build -t web-api .`

but a problem occurred:
`COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat WebAPI\WebAPI.csproj: file does not exist`.
I look forward to receiving everyone's help. Thanks

Comment: Is there a WebAPI.csproj file in the folder WebAPI? It is not visible in the image.

Comment: yes, there is a WebAPI.csproj file in the folder WebAPI @jolammi

Comment: Okay. I think Tschösi already answered your question. Just wondering, what are the contents of that .dockerignore that shows under Dockerfile? Is that just a thing VS does or is that a folder named Dockerfile?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, change `WebAPI/WebAPI.csproj` to `WebAPI.csproj`.

But please, in such cases, post your Dockerfile...